# autocorrelation function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have some data (theta vs time). I have to find the autocorrelation function and graph between autocorrrelation vs lag. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the Econometrics Toolbox, you can use [`xcorr`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html), which is part of the signal processing toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autocorr function from the Econometrics toolbox, it will calculate the autocorrelation.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/autocorr.html

If you do not own this toolbox, you have to write the autocorrelation function by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
%program of autocorrelation
clc;
fs=16000;
[file,path]=Uigetfile('*.wav');
speechsignal=wavread([path,file]);
f=1:2*fs;
ss1=speechsignal(16095:16700);
ss2=speechsignal(16095:16550);
ss3=speechsignal(16095:16400);

%Calculation of short time autocorrelation
[ac1,lag1]=xcorr(ss1);
[ac2,lag2]=xcorr(ss2);
[ac3,lag3]=xcorr(ss3);
figure;
plot(f,speechsignal);
title('input speech signal');
grid on;
figure;
plot(lag1,ac1);
title('short time autocorrelation of 606 sample');
figure;
plot(lag2,ac2);
title('short time autocorrelation of 456 sample');
figure;
plot(lag3,ac3);
title('short time autocorrelation of 306 sample');
figure;
subplot(2,2,1),plot(f,speechsignal);
subplot(2,2,2),plot(lag1,ac1);
subplot(2,2,3),plot(lag2,ac2);
subplot(2,2,4),plot(lag3,ac3);
```